# Trayecto de UISlider Altura Swift

Tags: swift, xcode

Actualmente tengo un UISLIDER que quiero pintar el trayecto y se ve asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al llegar al final el fondo queda

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La Clase que utlizo es

```
class CustomUISlider  : UISlider {
    
    @IBInspectable open var trackWidth:CGFloat = 2 {
        didSet {setNeedsDisplay()}
    }

    override open func trackRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        let defaultBounds = super.trackRect(forBounds: bounds)
        return CGRect(
            x: defaultBounds.origin.x,
            y: defaultBounds.origin.y + defaultBounds.size.height/2 - trackWidth/2,
            width: defaultBounds.size.width,
            height: trackWidth
        )
    }
    
   
}
```

y en el guion grafico le coloc la misma altura que el UISlider,

Porque el mismo se bugea de esa forma?, como podria solucionarlo, gracias..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te faltaría en tu clase hacer `override` de la función `layoutSubviews()` para que se modifique la capa del slider.

Entonces quedaría así:

```
class CustomUISlider  : UISlider {
    
    @IBInspectable open var trackWidth:CGFloat = 2 {
        didSet {setNeedsDisplay()}
    }

    override open func trackRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        let defaultBounds = super.trackRect(forBounds: bounds)
        return CGRect(
            x: defaultBounds.origin.x,
            y: defaultBounds.origin.y + defaultBounds.size.height/2 - trackWidth/2,
            width: defaultBounds.size.width,
            height: trackWidth
        )
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
    
        self.layer.sublayers![1].cornerRadius = 10.0//Aquí modificas las esquinas del slider.
    }  
}
```

Comment: Funciono muy bien muchas gracias Bicho Bicho

Comment: sabrias porque antes de llegar al 100% ya se pinta todo?

Comment: Creo que es algo del UX de Xcode, si cambias a que el slider sea mas delgado funciona bien. Cuando es el estilo muy ancho en 95 ya se pinta todo; que extraño.